# How do I get the length of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

How can I get the length of an array in C, I tried it how i get it in other languages but it doesn't work like this:

```
int array [5];

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {..
```

Comment: Did you search it on Google?

Comment: @haccks nope he didn't

Answer (score 5):

If its on the stack, you can use the `sizeof` **operator** to determine its raw byte size:

```
int array[5];
size_t array_size = sizeof(array);
```

But this gives you the size in bytes, not the number of elements. However, you can calculate the number of elements with this approach:

```
int array[5];
size_t array_elems = sizeof(array) / sizeof(* array);
```

If you array is a pointer (e.g. function call or dynamic memory allocation) then you have to keep track it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

Comment: downvote for correct solution?

Comment: Not my downvote. This answer is the same as that from @d3l but without any explanation. A good answer should explain why it is an answer. A short piece of code may be correct but it does not educate the asker.

Comment: but `size_t` is typedef as `unsigned long int`

Comment: Maybe, but so can it be typedef'd as `unsigned int` ;) Its implementation defined.

Comment: Not my downvote, but a copy-pasted code snippet is _not_ enough.